# Add timeout to Kubctl exec command

Tags: python, kubernetes

I have python 2.7 code that for each 1 min run command on running pods with the following:

```
file_exist = subprocess. \
    check_output("kubectl exec -it  " + pod_name + " -- ls " +
                 path + " >> /dev/null 2>&1 && echo yes || echo no", shell=True).rstrip()
return file_exist == "yes"
```

The problem I face with is `kubectl exec` command sometimes hang, How can I add timeout to  kubectl command to prevent my code to hang on  `kubectl exec` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use timeout parameter In `check_output()`

```
file_exist = subprocess. \
    check_output("kubectl exec -it  " + pod_name + " -- ls " +
                 path + " >> /dev/null 2>&1 && echo yes || echo no", shell=True,timeout=300).rstrip()
return file_exist == "yes"
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output

for `kubectl exec` timeout you can use `--request-timeout=30s`

Comment: --request-timeout flag is broken / not working as expected. see:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/49343

Answer (score 0):

If you are running kubectl out of cluster(i.e., not inside a pod), then you can use `--request-timeout` option of kubectl .

From [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/kubectl/)

```
--request-timeout string     Default: "0"
The length of time to wait before giving up on a single server request. Non-zero values should contain a corresponding time unit (e.g. 1s, 2m, 3h). A value of zero means don't timeout requests.
```

If you are running kubectl in-cluster(inside a pod using in-cluster config), then `--request-timeout` currently does not work. You can use the `timeout` parameter of `subprocess.check_output`. `subprocess.TimeoutExpired` exception is raised if the command times out.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output

Comment: If I run the command from master, Can I use --request-timeout ?

Comment: sure yes as long as you are running outside a pod.

Comment: So I  running the following: kubectl exec --request-timeout=5s -it my-deployment-9657c5476-b9csq -- ls /tmp/running
And It isn't done after 5 seconds, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The timeout is for "kubectl" itself i.e., if k8s api-server doesn't respond then it times out after given time. In your case if "kubectl exec" have worked and you might be attached to container's process.

Comment: So what can I  do  to add timeout?